# JQuery remove redundant code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following Jquery code on my custom.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    changePageAndSize();
    changeSortBy();
});

// Paging change page
function changePageAndSize() {
    $('#pageSizeSelect').change(
            function(evt) {
                // .... redundant code
            });
}
// End paging change page

// Sorting change
function changeSortBy() {
    $('#sortBySelect').change(
            function(evt) {
                // ... redundant code
            });
}
// End sorting change
```

1. How to remove duplicate code in function(evt)?

Comment: Put it in a same function ?

Comment: Why don't you just pass the event to another function?

Comment: `$(function() { $("#pageSizeSelect, #sortBySelect").on("change", function(evt) {...} });`

Comment: Thanks @Andreas  Exactly what I'm looking for `$(document).ready(function() {
 changeParameters();
});

function changeParameters() {
 $('#pageSizeSelect, #sortBySelect').change(
   function(evt) {
    //... function goes here
   });
}`

Comment: Add it as an answer and accept it to "close" this question properly :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Andreas. Here is the solution I wrote:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    changeParameters();
});

// change request param
function changeParameters() {
    $('#pageSizeSelect, #sortBySelect').change(
            function(evt) {
                // ... function goes here
            });
}
// End change request param
```